# Facebook Custom Story Map Attachment

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can't for the life of me get my custom story display in the Map layout. I have done this before but that solution is no longer working either so I'm starting to think something has changed.

**Current Setup**

I have a custom object type `Track` with a self-hosted object [here](http://corecoders.dyndns.org/s2tm/skitest.html) (please see the source code for object structure). This object has a required field called `route` which contains multiple `GeoPoints`. I will put the GeoPoints in another file at some point but that causes other problems at the moment.

I have a custom action called `Ski` that obviously has the field `Track` which references the object.

In my custom story which is `Ski a Track`, I have edited the attachment to be a map layout and set the Route to be `track.route`.

Now when I create an action which references my self-hosted object using the Graph API Explorer I get an ID back which means its been created. I can also see the story on my timeline.

**The Issue**

The story is always in the standard layout.

**My Question**

Is it possible to still use the map attachment. If so what am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

For those interested I have submitted a bug report [here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/820798267972000). For anyone also experiencing issues of this nature then please subscribe to it as Facebook may deem it important enough to sort out.

Comment: I am also having this issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26286101/facebook-open-graph-story-with-map-attachment

Comment: Please subscribe to the bug report I linked in my question. This will show that there's interest

Comment: Has anyone a solution to the problem?

Comment: @Stone apparently this was fixed according to the Facebook bug request I linked in my question. Although I have not tested it myself. Can you not get it to work?

Comment: @DiscoS2 the map style is never shown up in a post. But i need it.

btw: the Object style is working as expected.

Comment: @Stone, did you finally find a solution?