# Facebook Open Graph Story with Map Attachment

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-timeline

I have created a custom Open Graph story (Spot a Special). I would like to be able to post this to a user's wall with a map attachment, so I configured it as such:

[image]

I set the "Hilighted Points" attribute to "special.location"
 and defined the location attribute in my "special" object:

[image]

Then I try to post this story (using the Graph Explorer) using `https://graph.facebook.com/me/objects/ishoppapp:specialaccess_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&method=POST&object=MY_OBJECT`

**MY_OBJECT** being:

```
{
    "app_id":277886232371318,
    "type":"ishoppapp:special",
    "url":"http://ishopp.co.za/ogp.html",
    "title":"Sample Special",
    "description":"This is a huge description.",
    "data": {
                "discount": 20,
        "location": {
            "latitude": -33,
            "longitude": 18
        }
    }
}
```

And the og tags on http://ishopp.co.za/ogp.html are:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="277886232371318">
<meta property="og:title" content="Sample Spec">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://placehold.it/250x250">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://ishopp.co.za/ogp.html">
<meta property="og:type" content="ishoppapp:special">
<meta property="ishoppapp:discount" content="20" />
<meta property="ishoppapp:location:latitude" content="-33.00" />
```

However, when I post this, all I get is this: No map...
[image]

I have noticed that it says "posted" instead of "spotted". When use `/me/ishoppapp:spot/?special=http://ishopp.co.za/ogp.html` I get:
[image]

But still no map...

What is the fix for this?

Thank you.

Comment: I have the same problem, except that my object is not self-hosted. It seems to work if I use fitness.walks with fitness.course instead. If you come up with any news on this, please let us know.

Comment: It does work fine with the common fitness actions and the fitness.course object but not custom stories...

Comment: I'm following a couple bugs on FB about this. I can get mine to show up on my mobile phone, but not on a desktop browser.
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/672180779564949/
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/820798267972000/

Comment: Hi Jacques, did you find a solution then?

Answer (score 0):

I would add a comment to the question but i have not enough reputation for that so i add it here.

In the facebook bug report https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/820798267972000/ it says that the issue is already fixed but i still have the issue so i'have reopened the issue with the bug report: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1535630563354475 and it has been accepted by facebook.

If anyone wants subscribe to the bug report i suppose it will get more attention.